# How to import a file for different environment with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

There are two files under `src` folder.

- main.ts
- tracing.ts

I want to import `tracing` in the main.ts only on local environment.

main.ts

```
1 if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local') {
2   import './tracing'
3 }
4 import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
5 import others...
```

It can't use `process.env.NODE_ENV` at the beginning of the main file.

If I import it in the middle of the main file with other way, it said the import should at the top of the file.

```
const config = app.get(ConfigService);
if (config.get('TRACING_ENABLE')) {
  import './tracing'
}
```

How to import?

Comment: use dynamic imports eg: ```const tracing = await import('./tracing.js')```.

Comment: Keep in mind that `NODE_ENV === 'local'` does not exist and will default `NODE_ENV` to `development`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting bogdanoff's comment as an answer:

You can use [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "local") {
   await import('./tracing.js');
}
```